# Overriding Dart's local time zone

Tags: dart

Dart's `DateTime` only supports UTC and "local" time. Is there a way to specify a local time zone when running tests, short of changing the time zone on the machine running the tests (or replacing DateTime with a time-zone-aware library)? See e.g. Java's `user.timezone` system property.

Comment: Something like this? https://pub.dev/packages/timezone

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the timezone (and time_machine) package... What I'm looking for is a way to test code that uses the built-in DateTime class.

Answer (score -1):

I think the [clock package](https://pub.dev/packages/clock) should be useful.

Run you test inside `withClock()`

```dart
test('clock', () {
  withClock(Clock.fixed(DateTime.parse('2002-02-27T14:00:00-0500')), () {
    final date = clock.now(); // will be the same for each launch

    // your test here
  });
});
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how I can use this snippet to override the `.toLocal()` behavior inside my code. My code uses `DateTime.toLocal`, thus I'm not sure of what I can do with `clock.now` as suggested above.